# What is the ">?" LaTeX3 floating point operator

Tags: latex3, fp

The `l3fp` package documentation refers to the `>?` operator (page 237 of interface3.pdf) but I could not find any example or explanation there despite it is recognized as shown in next example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\fp_compare:nTF { 1 >? 2}
{⟨true code⟩} {⟨false code⟩}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\begin{joke}` It checks whether a given number is *maybe* bigger than another given number. `\end{joke}`

Comment: @Gaussler that is actually the intuition behind the notation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's documented under `\fp_compare:nTF`:

Any combination of the characters `!<=>?` can be used as a comparison operator (except that the first character can not be `?`). If a `!` is present the truth value is inverted. Otherwise the symbols `<=>?` stand for the cases which should be true. `<=>` are probably obvious, `?` stands for "not ordered" (mostly relevant for NaN and tuples).

So `>?` is "bigger or not comparable". It can also be written as `!<=` ("not less than or equal").